# Getting env varibles as undefined in react.js

Tags: reactjs

```
        const { URL } = process.env;
        alert(URL);
        export const API_URL = URL;
```

my consants File. Here i am using backend url from .env File.
But i am getting undefined when alert.

```
    URL=http://statrix.ru
```

Here is my .env File.

Please let me know whats wrong i am doing

Comment: Are you using create react app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using create-react-app to initialize your project so I think you should put prefix `REACT_APP` before your environment variable.

In this case, that should be

```
REACT_APP_URL=http://statrix.ru
```

and to get this variable in your javascript that should be

```
const { REACT_APP_URL } = process.env;
```

For more your information, please read official document at [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)